# Scala - how to correctly add ZoneOffset when combining LocalDate and LocalTime?

Tags: java, scala, datetime, time

I'm combining LocalDate and LocalTime and need the final result to be in UTC.

Should I add ZoneOffset.UTC to `localDate` and `localTime` before combining them or only when creating OffsetDateTime? I've tried different approaches but don't see a difference.

```
val localDate: LocalDate = java.time.LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC) // Same as without Offset - 2019-10-30
val localTime: LocalTime = java.time.LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC) // Same as without Offset - 09:55:25.997

val localDateTimeWithZone: OffsetDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, localTime)
    .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toOffsetDateTime
```

Comment: you first convert the LocalDateTime to ZonedDateTime by adding the Zoned/Offset (the timezone this time measurement belongs to) information to it. Then you change it to whatever TimeZone (probably UTC in your case) you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

- My preferred way is the following. I think it’s simple and pretty free from surprises.

  - `OffsetDateTime.of(localDate, localTime, ZoneOffset.UTC)`
- The following options are perfectly fine too.

  - `localDate.atTime(localTime).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`
  - `localTime.atDate(localDate).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`
  - `LocalDateTime.of(localDate, localTime).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`
- I find the following options more confusing. They work too, but personally I would not use them.

  - `localTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).atDate(localDate)`
  - `localDate.atTime(localTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC))`
  - `OffsetTime.of(localTime, ZoneOffset.UTC).atDate(localDate)`

The list is *not* exhaustive. All the above give the same result, and also the same result as the code in your question, an `OffsetDateTime` of your date and time in UTC. So you can make your pick.